# Wrong time from NSDateFormatter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, date, nsdateformatter

I have a string that I want to parse the time from:

```
NSString *longdate = @"Mar 27, 2011 8:38:38 PM";
```

I want to parse this date and output just the time portion w/ hours+minutes+am/pm:

```
// First, convert our string into an NSDate
NSDateFormatter *inFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];
NSDate *date = [inFormat dateFromString:longdate];
[inFormat release];

// Now convert from date back to a string
NSDateFormatter *outFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[outFormat setDateFormat:@"HH:mm aaa"];
NSString *final = [outFormat stringFromDate:date];
[outFormat release];

NSLog(@"original: %@ | final %@", longdate, final);
```

The problem is the final time is wrong. I expect the time to be 8:38 PM, but instead I get 12:38 PM.

I just want to get the same hour out that I put it, and not bother w/ any time zones or locales. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem. Had nothing to do with timezones and everything to do with using the wrong formatting codes for the date formatter.

```
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aaa"];
```

should be:

```
[inFormat setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy h:mm:ss aaa"];
```

Likewise, outFormat's dateformat should be:

```
[outFormat setDateFormat:@"h:mm aaa"];
```

After this adjustment everything works fine even w/o any TimeZone adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave said, check your time zones. You can tell the date formatter to use your current time zone as well:

```
[outFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your timezones messed up.  IIRC, `NSDateFormatter` (by default) will parse stuff in the UTC timezone (+000), but dates are `NSLog`ged in your current timezone.  Or something like that.

Anyway, check your timezones.