# NSString to NSDate conversion getting the wrong result

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdate, nsdateformatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wrong time from NSDateFormatter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5466419/wrong-time-from-nsdateformatter)
>   [NSDate is 5 hours off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7450510/nsdate-is-5-hours-off)

I am trying to convert NSString to NSDate with the code

```
result = @"2012-02-09";

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:result];
[dateFormatter release];
NSLog(@"date: %@", dateFromString);
```

But the date conversion giving an incorrect result, in logs:

```
2012-02-07 13:08:29.553 Document[611:15503] date: 2012-02-08 19:00:00 +0000
```

Can someone please tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Duplicate of 27,000,000 other SO questions - your time zone is GMT +5 (Pakistan), NSDate logs itself as GMT. Nothing is wrong with your code. If you want a local string value from a date, pass the date back through an NSDateFormatter, don't log it.

Comment: There is nothing wrong - you just need to set the time zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use NSLog to display a date you should use your formatter so that the NSDate will be formatted with your TimeZone:

```
NSLog(@"date: %@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString]);
```